# Does Biden OSHA vaccine mandate apply to remote workers?

Tags: united-states, employment, vaccination, osha

Does Biden vaccine mandate apply to remote workers? I am programmer full-time employee working from home. Our company was fully remote before the pandemic in 2019.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The emergency temporary standard requires either vaccination, or testing with masks for unvaccinated workers, for employees of an employer with 100 or more employees but has exceptions for employees working alone or exclusively outdoors.

According to [1910.501 - Vaccination, testing, and face coverings](https://www.osha.gov/laws-regs/regulations/standardnumber/1910/1910.501):

> 1910.501(b)(3)
> The requirements of this section **do not apply** to the employees of
> covered employers:
>
> 1910.501(b)(3)(i) **Who do not report to a workplace where other individuals such as coworkers or customers are present;**
>
> 1910.501(b)(3)(ii) **While working from home**; or
>
> 1910.501(b)(3)(iii) Who work exclusively outdoors.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132495/discussion-on-answer-by-xngtng-does-biden-osha-vaccine-mandate-apply-to-remote-w).

Answer (score 4):

While I do not believe it applies to your particular case, for Federal employees, and by extension contractors, [it is required for remote workers](https://www.saferfederalworkforce.gov/faq/vaccinations/) (emphasis mine).

> To protect the health and safety of the Federal workforce and to promote the efficiency of the civil service, all Federal employees covered by Executive Order 14043 and without a legally required exception need to be fully vaccinated by November 22, 2021, regardless of where they are working. **Employees who are on maximum telework or working remotely are not excused from this requirement**, including because employees working offsite may interact with the public as part of their duties and agencies may need to recall employees who are on maximum telework or working remotely.